# Splice from Array if index matches

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, angular.js

This code loops through an array called `$rootScope.watchlist` (uses AngularJS). It gets the current iteration of the loop to access that x iteration through `$rootScope.watchlist` and get the `id` index. If that matches the variable `titleID`, then it will splice (remove) that index only and then stop the foreach to stop unnecessarily continuing.

```
for (var i = $rootScope.watchlist.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if($rootScope.watchlist[i]['id'] == titleID) {
        $rootScope.watchlist.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing such? Possibly using .some()?

Comment: What exactly are you using this for in practice?

Answer (score 2):

A while back, I went through [these exercises](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/) about functional programming in JS and since then I strive to use those techniques whenever possible. Bear in mind that functional techniques can lead to slower code, since a function call is made for each iteration instead of just running code within a loop block, but hopefully it is easier to work with each array element in that fashion - e.g. would you read/type `if($rootScope.watchlist[i]['id'] == titleID) {` or `if(element['id'] == titleID) {`?

After reading [Igor's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/175174/120114) as well as [this article about `break` with respect to functional programming](http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/break-continue-loop-functional/), I believe the following should work:

```
$rootScope
.watchlist
.slice()         //  copy before reverse(), because reverse() is mutating
.reverse()
.some(function(element, i) {
    if(element['id'] == titleID) {
        $rootScope.watchlist.splice($rootScope.watchlist.length - 1 - i, 1);
        return true;
    }
});
```

#### Edit:

[Igor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10983/igor-soloydenko) suggests simplifying that callback passed to `some()`. You can use an [ES-6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to eliminate a few lines, like this:

```
.some((element, i) => (element['id'] == titleID)? $rootScope.watchlist.splice($rootScope.watchlist.length - 1 - i, 1) : false);
```

See a demonstration in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dAuBCuC8NJFuD4D0LvN1?p=preview). Click the button labeled *remove watcher* and see how the watcher is removed. This code presumes  `$rootScope.watchlist` is equivalent to `$rootScope.$$watchers`...

Comment: You showed a really useful technique! Nice improvement, Sam! I'd still compress the `.some()`'s body to this: `.some((element, elementIndex) => element['id'] != titleId ? false : ($rootScope.watchlist.splice($rootScope.watchlist.length - elementIndex - 1, 1), true))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what functional style might look like. Unfortunately, it requires index recalculation, and overall more verbose and complicated, even though it tries to go the ".some()" way. :)

I believe it's one of those cases where imperative code keeps things simple.

```
const indexFromRear =
  $rootScope
    .watchlist
    .slice()         //  copy before reverse(), because reverse() is mutating
    .reverse()       //  reverse, since the original code searches rear-to-front
    .findIndex(element => element['id'] == titleID);

if (indexFromRear >= 0) {
  const indexFromFront = $rootScope.watchlist.length - indexFromRear - 1;
  $rootScope.watchlist.splice(indexFromFront, 1);
}
```